# Why answers are not in order today?

Tags: support, answers, sorting

Today, each question has answers in an unsorted way. Before this I saw the answers of each question in sorted order by their upvotes. Is this a setting? If so, how do I change it? And if not, are you seeing same as me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just above the list of answers for any post, you will see the tabs 'active', 'oldest' and 'votes', which represent your desired ordering of answers. Click on the one that says '**votes**'.

I would imagine that you had previously (mistakenly) clicked on 'active' or 'oldest' to change your default ordering. This setting does appear to be persisted across different posts.
[image]

---